# How to hide <section> with a child for in this case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a loop for in a `<section>` :

```
<section>
    <h4 role="heading" aria-level="4">@lang('site.scope')</h4>
    <ul>
        @for( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
            @if( $card->{"gen_champ__q" . $i } == 1 )
                <li>@lang( 'questions-general.gen_champ_q' . $i . '_1' )</li>
            @endif
        @endfor
    </ul>
</section>
```

But I don't have data that meets my condition if (== 1). 
So, I would like to hide the complete section.

But I do not know how to do it, do you have an idea? If I go above my section, it will duplicate my content and that's not what I want.

Comment: You can use javascript/jquery to remove the section.Using jquery closest find the nearest section and remove it

Comment: You want to hide section if loop is not executed, am I right?

Comment: @MakashovNurbol Yes !

Comment: @wilsonrufus Never fix something local that can be avoided in the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will write the "header" of the section with the first < li> (and only the first) you have to write. And you will write the "footer" of the section only if any < li> was written.

```
@for( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
    @if( $card->{"gen_champ__q" . $i } == 1 )
        @if (!isset($doSection) && $doSection=true) 
            <section>
            <h4 role="heading" aria-level="4">@lang('site.scope')</h4>
            <ul>
        @endif    
              <li>@lang( 'questions-general.gen_champ_q' . $i . '_1' )</li>
    @endif
@endfor
@if (isset($doSection))
      </ul>
    </section>
@endif
```

EDIT: Just upgraded to avoid unneeded variable initialization.

Comment: i think it gives multi times </ul>  </section>

Comment: Impossible: the </ul></section> is ran OUTSIDE the for block

Comment: oh  my bad didn't see propely

Answer (score -1):

```
 @for( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)

   @if( ! empty( $card->{"gen_champ__q" . $i }) 
     && $card->{"gen_champ__q" . $i } == 1 )
  <li>@lang( 'questions-general.gen_champ_q' . $i . '_1' )</li>
   @endif
@endfor
```

Comment: Whilst this may solve OP's issue, you may want to put in some text explaining what you have added, why you have added it and the result of adding it.

Comment: @WillParky93 Thank you for your response. What I want is to hide the section above (with the title <h4>) and your code, although better than mine, will not solve my problem: /

Answer (score -1):

You can put one extra if before section starts.

```
   @if($i>0)
    <section>
        <h4 role="heading" aria-level="4">@lang('site.scope')</h4>
        <ul>
            @for( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
                @if( $card->{"gen_champ__q" . $i } == 1 )
                    <li>@lang( 'questions-general.gen_champ_q' . $i . '_1' )</li>
                @endif
            @endfor
        </ul>
    </section>
    @endif
```

Answer (score -1):

there is many way of doing this one of them is this .
In this when your condition meet then it print else not

```
 @for( $i = 1,$j=1; $i <= 4; $i++)
      @if( $card->{"gen_champ__q" . $i } == 1 )
        @if($j==1&&$j--)

            <section>
            <h4 role="heading" aria-level="4">@lang('site.scope')</h4>
            <ul>
        @endif   

        <li>@lang( 'questions-general.gen_champ_q' . $i . '_1' )</li>
    @endif
@endfor
@if($j==0)        
   </ul>
   </section>
@endif
```

hope this will help you!

Comment: @jeremy if this solution will help you then marked it as answer if not then let me know what you need

Comment: This solution only will work if there the result is == 1 in the first and fourth itineration. What if it is only ==1 in the second and third?

Comment: yes as jeremy use for loop means they know index so we can use start and last index make it easy and simple

Comment: It might be easy and simple but it is incorrect, because there will be four iterations, and you don't know which of them will evaluate to true.